# cypher delete is taking forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete data from neo4j using the following query:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {customerID: '16af89a6-832b-4bef-b026-eafea3873d69'})
MATCH (c)<-[r:DEPT_OF]-(dept:Dept)-[*]-(n2) WITH r, dept, n2 LIMIT 10 
DETACH DELETE r, dept, n2;
```

This statement is taking forever and not deleting anything when I inspect the dept node for example. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable length path without specifying an upper bound in this line:

```
MATCH (c)<-[r:DEPT_OF]-(dept:Dept)-[*]-(n2) WITH r, dept, n2 LIMIT 10
```

This will result in a lot of traversals. Does your data model allow for specifying an upper bound on the number of hops to match `n2`. Also, you should specify a label or labels for `n2`.

Also, you don't need to include `r` in the `DETACH DELETE` statement. Any existing relationships of a node being deleted will also be deleted when using `DETACH DELETE`.

**Edit**

The pattern `(dept:Dept)-[*]-(n2)` indicates a bidirectional path of **any** length (with no upper bound). To specify an upper bound on the variable length path simply replace the `(dept:Dept)-[*]-(n2)` piece of the pattern with `(dept:Dept)-[*1..3]-(n2)`. This will limit the length of the paths traversed to a maximum of three relationships between `(dept:Dept)` and `(n2)` (although this might not be appropriate for your data model). It would also be good to add labels and a relationship direction to the pattern (appropriate for your data model), something like:

```
MATCH (c)<-[r:DEPT_OF]-(dept:Dept)<-[:BELONGS_TO*1..2]-(n2:Product) WITH r, dept, n2 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I am not sure what the change is or should be? I am very new to neo4j. Can you change my cypher so that I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different issues in your query. Here are the one I've identified.

1. The number of paths discoverable by a variable length path query (let's assume the lower bound is 0 or 1) is roughly an exponential function of the maximum path length. That is, if every relevant node has `M` relationships, and the maximum depth being searched (or, if there is no upper bound, the maximum possible depth) is `N`, then in the worst case the number of possible paths is (M ^ N). For example, if we plug in `5` and `10` for `M` and `N`, we get `9,765,625` possible paths (and the same number of nodes and relationships to be deleted). This is probably the main reason why your query takes a long time.
2. A second major concern would be total failure of the query due to an out-of-memory situation in the neo4j engine, due to the potentially huge amount of data that needs to be in memory. You have apparently not encountered this yet, but you might. You could try to minimize the number of found paths by only matching complete paths (that is, paths in which the last node has no other node to connect to). I don’t know your data model, so I can’t show you a Cypher clause to do that for your data. But if you do this, your query would have to be modified to use all the nodes in the found paths rather than just the path end nodes.
3. The second `MATCH` clause will only match `dept` nodes that have at least one relationship other than `r`, because the default lower bound for a variable-length path is a length of 1. Therefore, this query will not delete `dept` nodes that have no other relationships. You could solve this by specifying a lower bound of `0`, as in: `[*0..]`.
4. You have a `LIMIT 10` on your `WITH` clause, so your query is only going to attempt to delete a few `dept` and `n2` nodes. Also, since you are not necessarily deleting complete paths, you may end up with “disconnected subgraphs” that are no longer connected to anything else. So, you *should* remove the `LIMIT` clause, even though that would make your query take even longer.
5. It is theoretically possible (but I don't know your data model) for an `n2` to be the same as `c`. If your data allows this to be possible, but you never want your query to delete `c`, you need to add a `WHERE` clause right after the relevant `MATCH` clause to prevent that (see below).
6. Since a `MATCH` clause filters out any matches where the same relationship is used twice, your second `MATCH` clause is actually doing extra work to ensure that none of the relationships in each variable length path matches `r`. Since your use case does not need this checking (after you fix item 5), you could avoid that unneeded check by splitting the second `MATCH` clause so that `r` is matched in its own clause.

Here is a sample fix for items 3, 4, 5, 6:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {customerID: '16af89a6-832b-4bef-b026-eafea3873d69'})
MATCH (c)<-[r:DEPT_OF]-(dept:Dept)
MATCH (dept)-[*0..]-(n2)
WHERE n2 <> c
DETACH DELETE dept, n2;
```

But, since the above does not solve items 1 or 2, your query could still take a very long time and/or fail. If you provide a more complete idea of your data model, we might be able to solve item 2. However, item 1 is the main issue, and may require rethinking your data model or possibly splitting the deletion into multiple queries.